# What is the purpose of the IPython.display.display_markdown() function?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I frequently need to produce Markdown formatted output in Jupyter notebook. The way I do it is:

```
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
display(Markdown('# This is a Title'))
```

This will produce a beautiful formatted output. However there also exists a function called `display_markdown()` that I would expect to do the same. But apparently it doesn't do anything at all. What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set `raw=True` since it is a raw markdown:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works. So when would I use raw=False then?

Comment: I think you would use `raw=False` when it is already a markdown instance and `raw=True` when it is a raw markdown text.

Comment: I see. Using `display_markdown(Markdown('# Hello world'))` works. But what is the difference to `display(Markdown('# Hello World'))` then? Both seem to do exactly the same. So there is no benefit in using `display_markdown`

Comment: [`display`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display) is a generic function which computes the representation to be displayed on different frontends. There are other functions which are written on top of that for particular type of display usage and also for ease e.g. `display_markdown`, `display_pdf`, `display_png` etc.